# Google Places API Autocomplete Can we reuse session token?

Tags: google-places-api

I'm using Google place API for autocomplete per session

I know session_token used to group together autocomplete.

But i don't can we reuse existing session_token when it will expire
and do we need create new session_token when refresh that page ?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/50452233/5140781

Answer (score 2):

> Warning: Be sure to pass a unique session token for each new session. Using the same token for more than one session will result in each request being billed individually. Using a version 4 UUID is recommended.

Based on [this page](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#session_tokens), reusing session token will cause *independent billing*, which means you'll **pay more** if you do that.