# Android Places SDK: Determining when AutocompleteSessionToken has expired

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places

I am using the new Places SDK in my Android app. One of the features that comes with it are `AutocompleteSessionToken`. As per docs

> Session tokens group the query and selection phases of a user search
>   into a discrete session for billing purposes. We recommend using
>   session tokens for all autocomplete sessions. The session begins when
>   the user starts typing a query, and concludes when they select a
>   place. Each session can have multiple queries, followed by one place
>   selection. Once a session has concluded, the token is no longer valid;
>   your app must generate a fresh token for each session.

The [class](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/places/api/model/AutocompleteSessionToken) seems to have only one method, `newInstance()`. I am trying to figure if there is a way to know if the session token expired so that I can generate a new one. Apparently, google would just start billing my query normally as if there was no token if it has expired. So how do I figure this out? Can't find any related info in the docs or online. Would appreciate any help. Thanks!!

Comment: Don't know its related to your question, FYI have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50452233/5110595)

Comment: @HemantParmar Thanks, I saw that question and there's good info there but this part isn't discussed. I am not sure if it is even possible or not.