# How can I test the session token for Google autocomplete API if it is working?

Tags: node.js, google-maps, google-places-api

I've read the documentation about Google's autocomplete API here:
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete
and I've added in the session token so all the autocomplete requests will be grouped into one main request.

Where can I test/see the request is being grouped into one? Whenever I try this out it is still showing the total numbers of request and not the grouped one in my API Overview dashboard. Am I looking in the wrong place? Is there some other page that shows this data or we really cannot test for this? I'd rather not get surprised by the billing once this is out.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/59265284/11742502